# javascript for loop checking shows error

Tags: javascript

```js
function check()
{
    var rowl=document.getElementsByClassName("tbody")[0].rows;
    for(var r=0;r<rowl.length;r++)
    {
        ch=document.getElementsByClassName("tbody")[0].rows[r].cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
        
        var tiderow=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[r];//rows[0].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
        for(var t=0;t<tiderow.rows.length;t++)
        {
            var noo=tiderow.rows[t].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
            console.log(noo);
            

        }
        
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this code, this prints correctly the subtable values.
[image: Before if condition] 
And I am checking each subtable value with the Main table cells[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5NME.png) value. If it is greater, then I am showing the error message.
But even though it is not greater it shows the error

```js
function check()
{
    var rowl=document.getElementsByClassName("tbody")[0].rows;
    for(var r=0;r<rowl.length;r++)
    {
        ch=document.getElementsByClassName("tbody")[0].rows[r].cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
        
        var tiderow=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[r];//rows[0].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
        for(var t=0;t<tiderow.rows.length;t++)
        {
            var noo=tiderow.rows[t].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
            console.log(noo);
            if(noo>ch)
            {
                console.log("Error occured");
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

[image: After inserting the if condition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do

```
parseInt(noo)>parseInt(ch)
```

else javascript will treat this variables as string so 5 is greater than 10

Answer (score 2):

Ah, but it *is* greater. You're comparing `"5"` to `"10"`. `"5"`, the string, is greater than `"10"`, the string. If you want to compare these as numbers, convert them to numbers before the comparison:

```
ch = Number(rowl[r].cells[2].childNodes[0].value);
var noo = Number(tiderow.rows[t].cells[1].childNodes[0].value);
```

Comment: What is this thing you're doing? Just use the unary operator `+`.

Comment: @AngelPolitis A matter of style. It always takes me just a little longer to figure out what's going on with the unary plus.

Comment: Surely, but since the only thing it does is convert something to a number, I believe it's just a matter of getting used to it. Great answer nonetheless! +1